# Dynamic options for my parameters SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I want to know that If I have 10 parameters and they look really bad when i use them on my report as they totally hide my report. So is there any option that i can leave two parameters as they were and put a advance search link and when anyone clicks on it so a separate browser window appears and those rest of the parameters should appears in it. and when the user selects those options that window should close and then the query runs in my report and show me my required result.

Comment: what are you using to display the reports? Report Manager?

Comment: I am using VS 2010 ASP.net Reports Website. after making and deploying  the reports in SSRS 2008

Answer (score 1):

your report URL should look like this:

```
http://<server_name>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<Folder>%2f<ReportName>&rs:Command=Render
```

if you have 10 parameters `par1`, `par2`,...,`par10` and add `&par1=10` on the end of the report URL, you will pass the value to the first parameter and the other will be empty but SSRS wont run the report, so your users can inform the other ones and then run the report

or you can set a default value to the parameter and set it to internal

another option that you have if you are using an application to display the reports, is get all the parameters on a previous screen and pass all them on the report URL adding `&rc:Parameters=false` to hide the parameters or &rc:toolbar=false to hide all the toolbar